# Can a braced list of numbers be used as an argument passed to a variadic function (or constructor)?

Tags: c++

Can a braced list of numbers {0x00, 0x01, 0x02} be used as an argument passed to a variadic function (or constructor) ?

In the code below, I can successfully compile and call this:

```
BlobClass blob('A', "xyz", 'B', sss, 'C');
```

but the following does not even compile:

```
BlobClass blob('A', {0x00, 0x01, 0x02},  'B', sss , 'C');
```

Is there a way to make it work with the following class?:

```
class BlobClass
{
protected:
    unsigned char data[512];

    void memcpy_var(unsigned char*) // variadic memcpy terminator
    {
    }

    template <typename... REMAINING>
    void memcpy_var(unsigned char* Dest, const std::string& Peeled, const REMAINING&... RemainingArgs){ // variadic memcpy for std strings
        size_t TheSize = Peeled.size();
        std::memcpy(Dest, Peeled.c_str(), TheSize);
        memcpy_var(Dest + TheSize, RemainingArgs...);
    }

    template <typename... REMAINING>
    void memcpy_var(unsigned char* Dest, const char* Peeled, const REMAINING&... RemainingArgs){    // variadic memcpy for C strings
        while (*Peeled != 0)
            *Dest++ = *Peeled++;

        memcpy_var(Dest, RemainingArgs...);
    }

    template <typename... REMAINING>
    void memcpy_var(unsigned char* Dest, const char& Peeled, const REMAINING&... RemainingArgs){    /// variadic memcpy for single Chars
        *Dest = Peeled;
        memcpy_var(Dest + 1, RemainingArgs...);
    }

public:
    template<typename... ARGS>
    BlobClass(ARGS&&... args) {         //Variadic constructor
        memcpy_var(&data[0], args...);
    }

    BlobClass();
}


int main()
{   
    std::string sss("str");

    BlobClass blob('A', "xyz", 'B', sss, 'C');              //This works fine
    BlobClass blob('A', {0x00, 0x01, 0x02},  'B', sss , 'C');       //This does not compile with the error: "no overloaded function takes 5 arguments"
}
```

I have tried adding the following function, but it does not work:

```
template <typename... REMAINING>
void memcpy_var(unsigned char* Dest, const std::initializer_list<int>& Peeled, const REMAINING&... RemainingArgs){  // variadic memcpy for an entire initialier list
    size_t TheSize = sizeof Peeled;
    std::memcpy(Dest, &Peeled, TheSize);
    memcpy_var(Dest + TheSize, RemainingArgs...);
}
```

P.S.
I know that this class has unsafe code because the memcpy_var() can overrun the data[512] buffer.  I sanitized the bounds checking code for brevity.

Comment: A braced list doesn't have a type

Comment: @NathanOliver Is there a workaround for this lack of type? e.g. some default or implicit type assignment/conversion/casting ?

Comment: Not really, but you could pass each argument through another function which creates the object for you instead if it's an initializer list, otherwise just forwards the argument. Use a variadic template and perfect forwarding.

Comment: @N00by  I don't know about perfect forwarding and variadic templates (only about variadic functions). Do you know of any materials explaining how to do this?

Comment: Okay, I'll post it as a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but the best way to do so is to specialize your function for `std::initializer_list<T>`, since I assume that you want to do something different for these.

A possible implementation could be something in the following direction

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <numeric>

int memcpy_var() {
    return 0;
}

template<typename T, typename ... Ts>
int memcpy_var(T val, Ts ...rest) {
    return val + memcpy_var(rest...);
}

template<typename T, typename ... Ts>
int memcpy_var(std::initializer_list<T> il, Ts ...rest) {
    return std::accumulate(il.begin(), il.end(), 0) + memcpy_var(rest...);
}

int main() {
    return memcpy_var({1, 2, 3}, 5);
}
```

In action: https://godbolt.org/g/Dx3nsm

Comment: This only helps if the initializer list is the first argument. From the looks of the OP, it's also wanted to support things like `memcpy_var(5, {1, 2, 3})`, and I don't think there's a general way to do that with any number of arguments and lists in any positions.

Comment: Ah yes, it only works as the first argument. While this is suboptimal, in general, you should almost always be able to put the initializer list as the first argument while calling. Is this a defect in the language or are we just not seeing a better solution?

Comment: So why does the compiler complain with the error " "no overloaded function takes 4 arguments" ?  ... when attempting to call: `memcpy_var('S', {1, 2, 3})`